# Matplotlib Line Graph from Pivot Table: Custom Color of Lines

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table, linegraph

Given the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2]
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['YYYYMM'],columns=['Group'],aggfunc=np.sum)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
t.plot(ax=ax)
```

Are there arguments in t.plot() that would allow me to specify the colors of each line?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide line styles:

```
t.plot(ax=ax, style=['yellow', 'red'])
```

[image]

Comment: Super idea that you change answer to full names of colors. ;) It seems better solution.

Comment: Yes, the one-letter versions ar only good  for quick testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ax.set_color_cycle(['red', 'black'])
```

[image: graph]

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2]
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['YYYYMM'],columns=['Group'],aggfunc=np.sum)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_color_cycle(['red', 'black'])
t.plot(ax=ax)
```

EDIT:

Very interesting, by it seems better is use full name of colors, because it is difference as Mike [1. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37281782/1):

```
t.plot(ax=ax, style=['yellow', 'red'])
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, it threw a deprecation warning to use set_prop_cycle, but either way, it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using Python 3.5 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Interesting, I use python 3.5 too.